# HTML5 form validation not working for pattern="\d{10}"

Tags: html, validation

I have the HTML:

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="enter some text" required maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$"><br />
        <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="enter a number" required maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}"><br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

When I enter a number with more than 10 digits in the 2nd field, and click Submit, as long as I have 1-10 letters in the first field, the form will be submitted.

I thought `pattern="\d{10}"` ensured the field had to have no more than 10 digits?

Comment: Thanks @Maarti, are there editor buttons to enter those code snippet comments?

Comment: Yes, the 7th icon (or press Ctrl+M).

Comment: Oh, excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [`pattern` attribute](https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/) only works with [the following `input` types](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/pattern-attribute/):

- `date`
- `email`
- `password`
- `search`
- `tel`
- `text`
- `url`

Because it doesn't work with `number`, your validation won't trigger.

To remedy this, I would reccomend using `type="text"` instead, as your pattern *already* explicitly requires a numeric input:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #container {width: 600px; max-width: 100%; margin: 1em auto;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="enter some text" required maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$"><br />
                <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="enter a number" required maxlength="10" pattern="^\d{10}$"><br />
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you help with a [browserify error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385821/cant-browserify-file) ?

Comment: Unlikely I'm afraid; I've never used either Mocha or Chai -- and that question appears to be unrelated to this one. However, if this particular question has been resolved, I'd recommend marking either of the two answers as a solution, as doing so removes the question from the 'unanswered questions' queue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max="9999999999"`:

```css
#container {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="enter some text" required maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$"><br />
        <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="enter a number" required max="9999999999"><br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I prefer Obsidian Age's answer better. :-)

Comment: Ok but with `type="number"`, you can't enter letters, you have the arrows in the input that allow user to increment/decrement the value and on mobile it pops out a numerical keyboard.